# Python: Como lograr que se creen rectangulos que al moverse el de adelante ocupen su lugar

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

estoy tratando de crear un juego tipo Snake gamre utilizando el widget Canvas de tkinter,al pasar el rectangulo blanco por encima del rojo se crea otro rectangulo verde detras del blanco que cuando el blanco se mueve una posicion el verde ocupa su lugar.
Intente de muchas formas lograr que se sigan creando rectangulos verdes que ocupen el lugar del siguiente al moverse pero solo logro que se cree un rectangulo verde que cumple con lo que quiero.

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esto? o es necesario usar pygame para esto

Aqui mi codigo:

```
import tkinter as tk 
import random


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Snake game")
root.geometry("+340+30")

Pantalla = tk.Canvas(root,width=600,height=600,bg="#212121")
Pantalla.pack()
Head = Pantalla.create_rectangle(300,300,330,330,fill="white")


#Pantalla.create_line(600, 30, 0, 30, fill="red")
for i in [30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300,330,360,390,420,450,480,510,540,570]:
    Pantalla.create_line(600,i,0,i,fill="#FAFAFA")
    Pantalla.create_line(i,600,i,0,fill="#FAFAFA")


direccion = ""
Contador = 1

def AgregarCubo():
    global Contador 
    Pantalla.create_rectangle(Pantalla.coords(Head)[0],Pantalla.coords(Head)[1],Pantalla.coords(Head)[2],Pantalla.coords(Head)[3],fill="green",tags = f"Cubo{Contador}")
    Contador+=1 
    print("A")
def Crearcomida():
    x = random.choice([30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300,330,360,390,420,450,480,510,540,570])
    y = random.choice([30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300,330,360,390,420,450,480,510,540,570])
    Pantalla.create_rectangle(x,y,x+30,y+30,fill="red",tags="food")

def Cambiardireccion(A):
    global direccion    
    direccion = A
def Mover():    
    global Contador
    if  Pantalla.find_withtag("food") == ():
        Crearcomida()
    if Pantalla.coords(Head) == Pantalla.coords("food"):        
        Pantalla.delete("food")             
        Crearcomida()
        AgregarCubo()

    if Contador > 1:    
        for i in range(1,Contador):
            Pantalla.delete(f"Cubo{i}")
            Pantalla.create_rectangle(Pantalla.coords(Head)[0],Pantalla.coords(Head)[1],Pantalla.coords(Head)[2],Pantalla.coords(Head)[3],fill="green",tags = f"Cubo{i}")

    if Pantalla.coords(Head)[2] == 630:     
        Pantalla.move(Head,-30,0)   

    elif Pantalla.coords(Head)[2] == 0:
        Pantalla.move(Head,30,0)

    elif Pantalla.coords(Head)[3] == 0:
        Pantalla.move(Head,0,30)

    elif Pantalla.coords(Head)[3] == 630:
        Pantalla.move(Head,0,-30)   
    else:
        if direccion == "Up":       
            Pantalla.move(Head,0,-30)       

        elif direccion == "Down":
            Pantalla.move(Head,0,30)

        elif direccion == "Left":
            Pantalla.move(Head,-30,0)

        elif direccion == "Right":
            Pantalla.move(Head,30,0)

        Pantalla.after(89,Mover)


root.bind("<Up>",lambda _:Cambiardireccion("Up"))
root.bind("<Down>",lambda _:Cambiardireccion("Down"))
root.bind("<Left>",lambda _:Cambiardireccion("Left"))
root.bind("<Right>",lambda _:Cambiardireccion("Right"))

Pantalla.after(89,Mover)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahora mismo en cada iteración eliminas todos los cuadrados que siguen a la cabeza y añades un nuevo rectángulo detrás de ella. Al hacer esto solo tendrás un rectángulo verde detrás de la cabeza como máximo.

Hay muchas formas de hacer esto, pero una de ellas puede ser, por cada llamada a `mover`:

- Guarda en una variable las coordenadas actuales de la cabeza.
- En función de la dirección y la posición de la cabeza, la mueves a dónde sea necesario como ya hacías.
- Iteras sobre cada uno de los cuadrados del cuerpo y los mueves de forma encadenada a dónde estaba el cuadrado que le precede. Es decir, el cuadrado 1 lo mueves a dónde estaba la cabeza, el 2 a dónde estaba el 1 y así sucesivamente.

Existen más formas de hacer esto, por ejemplo, eliminado el último cuadrado y añadiendo uno dónde estaba la cabeza. Otra forma es mover el último cuadrado a dónde estaba la cabeza.

```
import tkinter as tk 
import random


root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Snake game")
root.geometry("+340+30")

pantalla = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=600, bg="#212121")
pantalla.pack()
pantalla.create_rectangle(300, 300, 330, 330, fill="white", tags="Cubo1")

#Pantalla.create_line(600, 30, 0, 30, fill="red")
for i in range(30, 600, 30):
    pantalla.create_line(600, i, 0, i, fill="#FAFAFA")
    pantalla.create_line(i, 600, i, 0, fill="#FAFAFA")

direccion = ""
contador = 2

def agregar_cubo():
    global contador 
    pantalla.create_rectangle(pantalla.coords(f"Cubo{contador - 1}"),
                              fill="green",
                              tags = f"Cubo{contador}"
                              )
    contador += 1 

def crear_comida():
    x = random.choice(range(30, 600, 30))
    y = random.choice(range(30, 600, 30))
    pantalla.create_rectangle(x, y, x + 30, y + 30, fill="red", tags="food")

def cambiar_direccion(a):
    global direccion    
    direccion = a

def mover():    
    if  not pantalla.find_withtag("food"):
        crear_comida()

    last_coords = pantalla.coords("Cubo1")

    if last_coords == pantalla.coords("food"):
        pantalla.delete("food")
        crear_comida()
        agregar_cubo()

    if last_coords[2] == 630:
        pantalla.move("Cubo1", -30, 0)

    elif last_coords[2] == 0:
        pantalla.move("Cubo1", 30, 0)

    elif last_coords[3] == 0:
        pantalla.move("Cubo1", 0, 30)

    elif last_coords[3] == 630:
        pantalla.move("Cubo1", 0, -30)  

    else:
        if direccion == "Up":
            pantalla.move("Cubo1", 0, -30)

        elif direccion == "Down":
            pantalla.move("Cubo1", 0, 30)

        elif direccion == "Left":
            pantalla.move("Cubo1", -30, 0)


        elif direccion == "Right":
            pantalla.move("Cubo1", 30, 0)

    for i in range(2, contador):
        coords = pantalla.coords(f"Cubo{i}")
        pantalla.coords(f"Cubo{i}", last_coords)
        last_coords = coords

    pantalla.after(250, mover)


root.bind("<Up>", lambda _: cambiar_direccion("Up"))
root.bind("<Down>", lambda _: cambiar_direccion("Down"))
root.bind("<Left>", lambda _: cambiar_direccion("Left"))
root.bind("<Right>", lambda _: cambiar_direccion("Right"))

pantalla.after(250, mover)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]